# Reusing Expression result in parent Expression

Tags: c#, expression-trees

Say I have a function that combines two child `Expression` (all `Expression` will return an `int`) according to the rule "ab + a":

```
public Expression CustomCombine(Expression a, Expression b)
{
    Expression mult = Expression.Multiply(a, b);
    return Expression.Add(mult, a);
}
```

If I compile and run the resultant `Expression`, is the compiler smart enough to know that the argument `a` doesn't need to be explicitly evaluated twice internally? The `Expression` trees for `a` and `b` may be quite lengthy and expensive.

If, in fact, the resultant `Expression` would evaluate `a` twice, then what is the best way to cache the value for reuse?

For example, I was wondering if maybe this would work (but it is unclear to me if an `ConstantExpression` can hold an `Expression` result determined at runtime):

```
public Expression CustomCombine(Expression a, Expression b)
{
    Expression aVal = Expression.Constant(a);
    Expression mult = Expression.Multiply(aVal, b);
    return Expression.Add(mult, aVal);
}
```

Note: I am aware this could be refactored as "a(b+1)" but my original question holds as I have other combinations which may reuse `a` or `b` many times in ways that can't be similarly factored. For example, "a<sup>2</sup> + ab + b<sup>2</sup>".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, in case of original expression it will be evaluated twice, but you can cache it. `Expression.Constant` won't work in that case as it requires constant value, and it needs to be evaluated during expression execution, but you can use `Expression.Variable` to declare new variable and then `Expression.Assign` to save `a` value to that variable and then declare `Exression.Block` with these expressions, as `Variable` requires own block. 
You can do the same for `b` variable if you want.

Following code will generate such expression:

```
(obj) => { int cached = obj.A; return cached*obj.B + cached; }
```

Here is sample code:

```
using System;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ParameterExpression param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Test), "obj");
        Expression a = Expression.Property(param, "A");
        Expression b = Expression.Property(param, "B");
        Expression result = CustomCombine(a, b);

        var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<Test, int>>(result, new ParameterExpression[] { param });
        Func<Test, int> func = lambda.Compile();

        var obj = new Test();
        var val = func(obj);

        Console.WriteLine("Result is " + val);
    }

    private static Expression CustomCombine(Expression a, Expression b)
    {
        var variable = Expression.Variable(a.Type, "cached");
        var aVal = Expression.Assign(variable, a);

        var mult = Expression.Multiply(variable, b);
        var result = Expression.Add(mult, variable);
        // here we are making Block with variable declaration and assigment
        var block = Expression.Block(new ParameterExpression[]{variable}, aVal, result);
        return block;
    }
}

public class Test
{
    public int A
    {
        get
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Property A is accessed");
            return 42;
        }
    }

    public int B
    {
        get
        {
            return 1;
        }
    }
}
```

And working .NetFiddle sample - https://dotnetfiddle.net/bfYVbv

Comment: Thanks, this is precisely what I was looking for.